# jquery cycle is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

In my site `jquery.min.js`   and  `jquery.cycle.all.latest.js` loading properly.
but images are not rotating [Please see this link](http://smsiland.com/a).
What is the problem please tell me.

Comment: Check the developer console?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Comment: I saw it using chrome Inspect Element

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com  and jQuery Cycle Plugin 
  Version: 2.88

Answer (score 0):

that is because  you are calling `FB.getLoginStatus` before it is initialized ... check you console ... try it removing the FB plugins first..

Comment: Should i call FB.getLoginStatus after jqury and cycle plug in

Comment: have you tried removing the Fb plugin first.... and see if your cycle is working..

Comment: ok i  could see you have your HTML invalid... please view source and check it out... you have 3 `<html> <head>` and so on... u need to fix that first..

Comment: i didnt find more than one html opening closing